# rerun failed tests junit5 cucumber

Tags: junit5, cucumber-java

I am trying to use this to implement a rerun mechanism for junit5 cucumber tests

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.artsok</groupId>
    <artifactId>rerunner-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Here are versions of junit and cucumber that I am using

`junit-jupiter-api` version is `5.7.0`
`cucumber-java` version is `6.9.1` and
`cucumber-junit-platform-engine` version is `6.9.1`

But I am receiving this error when I compile

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/ScriptEvaluationException
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ScriptEvaluationException
```

When I downgraded `junit-jupiter-api` version to `5.4.2` as `5.7.0` was conflicting with `rerunner-jupiter` in maven dependency tree , I started to get this error

```
org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
org/junit/platform/commons/PreconditionViolationException
```

If there's any other way I can achieve rerun in junit5 cucumber tests , I am open to utilize that too

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Dependency conflicts aside.

Unfortunately what you are trying to do is fundamentally not possible. JUnit 5 consists of three parts, the JUnit Platform, JUnit Jupiter and JUnit Vintage. The latter two are test engine implementations on the JUnit Platform. And so is the Cucumber JUnit Platform Engine.

The `rerunner-jupiter` extends JUnit Jupiter. Extensions are not part of the JUnit Platform and so you can't use them with Cucumber.

Comment: Is there any other way I can have rerun implement with junit5 and cucumber ?

Comment: Have a look at the Platform Launcher api. It will create a test plan to execute. You can also create a new plan by selecting the failed tests for a second execution. Nothing out of the box but the api is nice.

Answer (score 1):

If you use maven-surefire-plugin (of maven-failsafe-plugin), the configuration parameter `rerunFailingTestsCount` supports, since the version 3.0.0-M4 of the plugin, rerunning JUnit 5 based tests.

That includes the Cucumber JUnit Platform Engine.

More info: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#rerunFailingTestsCount

Comment: Although..., bear in mind that Surefire does not report properly the tests results (yet).
See:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1896
and
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1849